# Flask server won't start when I include logging.basicConfig(filename='whatever.log')

Tags: python, flask, logging

I have a flask app in which I'm implementing logging into a file. The code is as follows:

```
from flask import request, Flask
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(filename='fileStorage.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

print('helloworld')
```

When I enter >flask run I get the following response:

```
* Serving Flask app "PostData.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
helloworld
```

For some reason, the text `* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` Doesn't appear. It will appear, however, if I don't set the 'filename' parameter in logging.basicConfig

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe doublecheck the file/dir permissions to write into the logfile.

Comment: Does it create a fileStorage.log after you exit the application? If so, what are the contents of it?

Comment: Why `secure_filename` is imported? Is your actual code using it but not shared here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're not founding the message `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` (Flask server not starting when you include the `logging.basicConfig(filename='fileStorage.log', level=logging.DEBUG)` line in your code) on your console. This is likely due to the way the Flask development server and logging interact. Let's walk through the issue and provide a solution:

The Flask development server captures the standard output (`stdout`) and standard error (`stderr`) streams to display server-related information and responses. When you use the `logging.basicConfig(filename='fileStorage.log', level=logging.DEBUG)` line, it redirects the stdout stream to the log file, which prevents the Flask server information from being displayed on the console.

To overcome this issue and have both the Flask server information and logging messages in the same console, you can **configure the logging module to log to both the file and the console**. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve that:

```
from flask import request, Flask
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

# Create a logger instance
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create a file handler for writing logs to the file
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('fileStorage.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create a stream handler for displaying logs in the console
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create a formatter and attach it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

logger.debug('Debug message: This will appear in both the file and console.')
logger.info('Info message: This will appear in both the file and console.')

print('helloworld')  # This will now be displayed in the console
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return 'Hello, World! This is my Flask app.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

###### What actually happened when you go with your version of code?

I believe you have the following code in your `PostData.py` file  i.e.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

that's why you're getting the message `* Serving Flask app "PostData.py"` in your response. If you'll look at the content of your `fileStorage.log` file, you'll see one of the missing response message i.e. `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`. Here your server is still running but you're not getting message due to reason i describe above. If you'll put the route in your `PostData.py` and after running your app, you'll see some response, which depicts your serve is alive(running). For instance if i put the following route, i'll got the `Hello, World! This is my Flask app.` on my browser:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World! This is my Flask app.'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, although I don't understand why you add formatter or route code to your example. Without it, the answer would be perfect, I upvoted anyway.

Comment: I add route to verify in the browser that the server is running correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change your logging configuration as suggested in the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/logging/#basic-configuration), to something like:

```
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
            'formatter': 'default'
        },
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'app.log',
            'mode': 'w'
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'file']
    }
})


app = Flask(__name__)
```

When I run the above configuration, I get this in the console:

```
$ python3 main.py
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: on
[2023-08-30 02:28:31,307] INFO werkzeug: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
 * Running on http://172.31.196.81:3000
[2023-08-30 02:28:31,308] INFO werkzeug: Press CTRL+C to quit
[2023-08-30 02:28:31,310] INFO werkzeug:  * Restarting with stat
[2023-08-30 02:28:32,652] WARNING werkzeug:  * Debugger is active!
[2023-08-30 02:28:32,660] INFO werkzeug:  * Debugger PIN: 878-137-088
[2023-08-30 02:28:32,680] INFO werkzeug: 172.31.196.1 - - [30/Aug/2023 02:28:32] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[2023-08-30 02:28:32,684] INFO werkzeug: 172.31.196.1 - - [30/Aug/2023 02:28:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2023-08-30 02:28:32,694] INFO werkzeug: 172.31.196.1 - - [30/Aug/2023 02:28:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and my `app.log` file contains:

```
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 878-137-088
172.31.196.1 - - [30/Aug/2023 02:28:32] "[33mOPTIONS * HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
172.31.196.1 - - [30/Aug/2023 02:28:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.31.196.1 - - [30/Aug/2023 02:28:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```